# Unable to access appsettings.json file in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, appsettings

I was trying to access my web.config values in Azure Function, but then I came to know that we have to add config values in appsettings.json.

I  made those changes and uploaded appsettings.json at azure function location but no luck. my azure function is not reading the values kept in json file.

Please suggest way forward.

Comment: What is the your Azure function project target framework? .NET Core or something else?

Comment: 1.0.11490.0 this is my azure function version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your Function App via `Application settings` menu item, see [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings).

`appsettings.json` or other config files are ignored.

Comment: Yes, agree final option is this only. But this is really time consuming process for me as my config has more than 100 keys.

Comment: @SharadG You can use `func` CLI to publish settings from your `local.settings.json`

Answer (score 1):

The file local.settings.json stores app settings, connection strings, and settings for Azure Functions Core Tools. It has the following structure:

```
{
      "IsEncrypted": false,   
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connection string>", 
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<connection string>" 
      },
      "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071, 
        "CORS": "*" 
      },
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "SQLConnectionString": "Value"
      }
    }
```

We could get more info about Local settings file from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file).

> These settings can also be read in your code as environment variables. In C#, use [System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) or 
>   [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In JavaScript, use process.env. Settings specified as a system environment variable take precedence over values in the local.settings.json file.

Comment: Actually as said by @Mikhail appsettings.json gets ignored.

Comment: As Mikhail mentioned that you could use the func CLI to publish settings from your local.settings.json  `func azure functionapp publish azurefunctionname --publish-local-settings`.